# Can the OUTPUT clause create a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, output-clause

I'm doing an update like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET BirthDate = b.BirthDate
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
```

And I want to use the OUTPUT clause to back up my changes.

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET BirthDate = b.BirthDate
OUTPUT 
    inserted.Id, inserted.BirthDate AS New_BirthDate, 
    deleted.BirthDate AS Old_BirthDate
    INTO OutputTable
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
```

What I want to know is if there is a way for the OUTPUT clause to create the table OutputTable or do I have to make sure it already exists before running the statement?

Comment: [There's always the `OPENROWSET` hack...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1228165/73226)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, the target table must exist, though [the documentation is not explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) and probably should be. I can't see anything in the syntax diagram that would support any type of extension to create the output table at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

Aaron Bertrand is right. The documentation for the `OUTPUT` clause is not explicit in saying that a table cannot be created with its use. I've run into the same issue. What I ended up doing was using two statements:

```
--This creates the table with the needed columns without inserting any data.
SELECT TOP 0 [myColumn1], [myColumn2], ...etc
INTO [myNewTable]
FROM [myTable]

--This updates the records and inserts the updated data into the new table.
UPDATE [myTable]
SET [myColumn1] = 'Some Value',
    [myColumn2] = 'Some Other Value', ...etc
OUTPUT 
    [myColumn1], [myColumn2], ...etc
    INTO [myNewTable]
FROM [myTable] ...etc.
```

I know this answer is coming a bit late, but I hope it helps anybody else who is running into similar issues. Happy scripting!

Comment: The `OUTPUT` columns should be prefixed with `inserted` or `deleted` (depending on one needs).

Answer (score -3):

Use a subquery.

Into an existing table:

```
insert into dbo.ExistingTable
select * 
from
    ( 
    UPDATE dbo.Table1
    SET BirthDate = b.BirthDate
    OUTPUT 
        inserted.Id, inserted.BirthDate AS New_BirthDate, 
        deleted.BirthDate AS Old_BirthDate
    FROM Table1 a
    JOIN Table2 b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
    ) as UpdatedRows
```

Creating a new table:

```
select * 
into dbo.NewTable
from
    ( 
    …
    ) as UpdatedRows
```

The `into` keyword in the `output` clause can, as far as I know, only be used to put the results into a table-typed local variable.

Comment: This was a great idea but when I tried it out I got the following error: `A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.`